# Is it possible to use a $variable instead of 'row.table' in a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM purch_inv WHERE '".$anyrow."'='".$anyrecord."'";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM '".$table."' WHERE 'rowabc'='".$anyrecord."'";
```

I have been trying this but it is not working, any ideas?

Comment: no need to wrap `$table` and `$anyrow` with single quotes

Answer (score 1):

In php you could use variables in double quotes (ex.)

```
$name = 'John';
$var = "Hello $name!";
```

It shows: **Hello John**.

With single quotes (ex.)

```
$name = 'John';
$var = 'Hello $name!';
```

It shows: **Hello $name**.

Answer (score 1):

Single-quotes mark a string literal.
But you want identfiers;

```
SELECT * FROM identifier1 WHERE identifier2='stringliteral'
```

a table name is an identifier. Identifiers 
always can (and sometimes must) be wrapped in backticks.

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM `foo`
```

When I said a table name is an identifier, that wasn't entirely correct. In `SELECT ... FROM foo` foo is a *name*; it just so happens to be comprised of only one identifier, which is the table name.
There can be compound or multiple-part names, consisting of multiple identifiers connected via a dot between the parts. In that case you can (or must) wrap each single identifier in backticks; not the the whole name

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM `mydatabase`.`foo`
```

The fields you select (i.e. x,y and z in this case) are also names; so the same rules apply

```
SELECT `x`,`y`,`z` FROM `mydatabase`.`foo`
```

and again, in case you have multipart names you have to wrap each identifier individually in backticks, not the whole name

```
SELECT
    `foo`.`x`,
    `bar`.`x`,
    `foo`.`y`,
    `bar`.`z`
FROM
    `foo`
JOIN 
    `bar`
ON
    `foo`.`x`>`bar`.`y`
```

So, when do you use single quotes?
When you want a literal string in your query, like e.g.

```
SELECT x,y FROM foo WHERE y='abc'
```

this tells the MySQL parser that you want to compare the value of the field `y` to the string (literal) `abc` while

```
SELECT x,y FROM foo WHERE y=`abc`
```

would compare the value of the field `y` to the value of the field `abc` (which in my example doesn't exists and would therefore raise an error)

Full circle back to your question

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `rowabc`='$anyrecord'";
```

But please keep a good eye on http://docs.php.net/security.database.sql-injection regarding $anyrecord.
And make sure it is *you* (not the user) who is in control of $table.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

but you can't qoute the table name and column name

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE rowabc='".$anyrecord."'";
```

the other example should be like this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM purch_inv WHERE ".$anyrow."='".$anyrecord."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to think about SQL injection with the variables getting passed into your select query!  So because [table and column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter), you could use a function to create a whitelist of table names to pass into your query, then use a function with PDO to execute the statement:

```
$myWhitelist = array('table1', ...)

$myTable= array_intersect_keys($table1, array_flip($whitelist));
```

So now $table1 is safe to pass into your select function:

```
function select($conn, $table1, $someColumn) {
$myvar = $conn->prepare("SELECT FROM ".$table1." WHERE id = :someColumn");
$myvar->bindParam(":someColumn", $someColumn, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$myvar->execute();  

if ($myvar->rowCount() > 0) {
        return true;
} else {
        return false;
}
```

}